# How can I become familiar with flight rules specific to Canada when flying there from the United States?

Tags: international, canada

As a US licensed and trained pilot, I know I can fly into Canada, but are there are airspace rules that are different from the American system. Is there a Canadian rules test or conversion you can or should do, or should I just expect to fly in Canada by the exact same rules and procedures as in the United States?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the specific case of Canada, AOPA and COPA have a lot of information aimed at US pilots. AOPA has a [complete guide](http://www.aopa.org/Flight-Planning/Canada) on documents, customs etc. and COPA has [a page](https://copanational.org/en/flyingtocanada/) with more information, which includes this remark:

> The flying rules are almost indistinguishable - reading the COPA guide
>   should keep you legal and out of trouble. Make sure you get a Canada
>   Flight Supplement (CFS) and some VNCs (Canadian equivalent to your US
>   sectionals), that will allow you to navigate VFR safely.   IFR plates
>   are available from Nav Canada as a subscription or the (sample list
>   of) vendors included below. (by mail order)

The guide is free but available to AOPA/COPA members only.

Comment: That's great! Thanks!

Comment: Your second link is broken, plus there are some other operational differences (for instance, [there is a difference in climb/descend via clearances](https://www.nbaa.org/ops/intl/nam/canada-sid-star/) between the two countries that get some pilots in to trouble).

Comment: @Lnafziger Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to know the differences.
A big one is all airspace between 12500 and 18000ft is Class B.
So you need either an IFR or VFR clearance.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_airspace
  Class B airspace is any controlled airspace between 12,500 ft (3,800 m) and 18,000 ft (5,500 m) Occasionally, Class B airspace exists in other locations, though this is unusual.

https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/publications/tp15048-menu-5859.htm
Class B     Controlled low-level airspace (above 12 500 ft ASL, up to 18 000 ft ASL); IFR and CVFR only.